# Preset runtime parameters for a docker container

Tags: docker

Is there any way to define some default parameters for a docker container?
***For example***, I'd like to set up logging options (`docker run ... --log-driver syslog --log-opt syslog-address=udp://logger:514 ...`), but I'm sure, I'll forget it when I issue docker run command, a few days later.
Can I define parameters like this, at build time?
Or do I need to create a startup script?

Answer (score 1):

To do it globally you can configure logging by creating `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and specyfing the `log-driver` value.

Documentation:

[Configure the default logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I want. Logging driver is just an example, it could be any other runtime arguments, accepted by docker run command. And I'd like to configure it by container, not globally.

Comment: Then the best option is just use docker-compose, where you can specify whatever you want.